# Join extracted/splitted patches to reconstruct an image

Tags: python, image-processing

i used this code below to extract patches from a image.

extract code:

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None # to avoid image size warning

imgdir = "/path/to/image/folder"
filelist = [f for f in glob.glob(imgdir + "**/*.png", recursive=True)]
savedir = "/path/to/image/folder/output"

start_pos = start_x, start_y = (0, 0)
cropped_image_size = w, h = (256, 256)

for file in filelist:
    img = Image.open(file)
    width, height = img.size

    frame_num = 1
    for col_i in range(0, width, w):
        for row_i in range(0, height, h):
            crop = img.crop((col_i, row_i, col_i + w, row_i + h))
            name = os.path.basename(file)
            name = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
            save_to= os.path.join(savedir, name+"_{:03}.png")
            crop.save(save_to.format(frame_num))
            frame_num += 1
```

Now i want to reconstruct this imagem from all those patches extracted before, i've tried 2 diffenret codes
so my DB is 120x256x256x3 extracted patches, theres 120 patches to fit in 3840x2048 shape..:

```
patches = []
for directory_path in glob.glob('D:\join_exemplo'):
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.png")):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path,1)
        patches.append(img)
input_patches = np.array(patches)
```

first i've tried sklearn.feature_extraction.image importing reconstruct_from_patches_2d, but got a black image:

```
reconstruct = reconstruct_from_patches_2d(input_patches, input_image)
reconstruct = reconstruct.astype(np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(reconstruct, 'RGB').save(r'D:\join_exemplo\re\re3.png')
```

also tried, this below but got a grayscale tone pattern image

```
input_image = (3840,2048,3)
reconstructed_arr = np.zeros(shape=(3840,2048,3))


#%%

>>> step = 256
>>> for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            x_pos, y_pos = x * step, y * step
            reconstructed_arr[x_pos:x_pos + 512, y_pos:y_pos + 512] = img[x, y, 0, ...]
>>> (input_image == reconstructed_arr).all()
True


cv2.imwrite(r'D:\join_exemplo\re\re.png',reconstructed_arr)
```

Can someone see whats wrong? sorry about my bad english

Comment: what's your best attempt to solve this yourself? you are expected to show an effort. please review [ask].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry, first time using stackoverflow and also newbie in coding

Comment: they've been taken in a regular grid, so you can just reassemble them the same, right? you only need to make one big blank image, and then copy those pieces back where they belong